# How to find a Bundle in INSTALLED state?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

If a bundle's dependencies can not be resolved, it should be in INSTALLED state. Then how to find it ?

I tried

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle( symbolicName ) ;
```

but `bundle` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `Platform.getBundle` internally it uses `FrameworkWiring` to do the search but filters out bundles only in INSTALLED (or UNINSTALLED).

This is an adapted version of that code without the filtering:

```java
String symbolicName = // Bundle to find

FrameworkWiring wiring = Platform.getBundle(org.osgi.framework.Constants.SYSTEM_BUNDLE_SYMBOLICNAME).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class);

String filter = '(' + IdentityNamespace.IDENTITY_NAMESPACE + '=' + symbolicName + ')';

Map<String, String> directives = Map.of(Namespace.REQUIREMENT_FILTER_DIRECTIVE, filter);

Collection<BundleCapability> matching = wiring.findProviders(ModuleContainer.createRequirement(IdentityNamespace.IDENTITY_NAMESPACE, directives, Collections.emptyMap()));
```

There may be several matches if multiple versions are present.

With `BundleCapability` call `getRevision().getBundle()` to get the bundle.

Comment: I tried, but the `matching ` is empty.

Comment: The bundle I'm looking for, one of its dependencies is missing.

Comment: Then I imagine it is not Installed, my guess is it is not known at all -but I don't know any details about how that works.